# Subscribing to events using ethers / hardhat network

Tags: nodejs, ethers.js, websocket, hardhat, express

I have a basic node express application. It connects to my locally running hardhat network via ethers & websocket. The connection seems to work, since I can query the blockchain succesfully (for instance `await ethers.getBlockNumber()` returns the correct block number).

However, my event listeners do not seem to work. The callbacks are never triggered.

**Code example:**
I'm using a loader function when I initialize the express app. When it is executed, I connect to the websocket provider. Then I successfully print the current block number to the console. Then I register an event listener on the "block" event (taken from the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--event-methods)). However, the listener never fires.

I'm connecting to the hardhat network, which is configured to produce a new block every five seconds (I can see that this is the case in the hardhat console). I would expect the listener to be fired every five seconds, always when a new block is mined.

What am I missing?

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export default async ({ expressApp }) => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
    "ws://localhost:8545"
  );

  console.log(await provider.getBlockNumber());

  provider.on("block", () => console.log("new block"));

  expressLoader({ app: expressApp });
};
```

**EDIT:**
If I use the `JsonRpcProvider`instead of `WebSocketProvider`and the following url `http://localhost:8545` the callbacks are fired. What do I need to do to achieve the same behavior with websocket?

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same issue.

nomiclabs has related open [issue](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/588)

```
provider.on("block", () => console.log("new block"));
```

Above code works via http -- because it has interval polling strategy underneath. So it is not notified via ws subscription, but requesting is there a new block.